# What needs to be enabled to support curl -I?

Tags: curl, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an AWS instance failing a custom health check.
If I hit the health check directly, it passes:

```
curl -v http://localhost:8080/batch/health
```

produces the 200/OK reponse as expected:

```
* About to connect() to localhost port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying ::1... connected
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /batch/health HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7     NSS/3.16.2.3 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: localhost:8080 
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< ETag: "0d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"
< Content-Type: text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Wed, 19 Aug 2015 14:38:40 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

Now the [AWS troublshooting checklist](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/ts-elb-healthcheck.html#ts-elb-healthcheck-targetpage) recommends using curl -I, which retrieves only the headers.  And indeed, this fails on my instance:

```
curl -I "http://localhost:8080/batch/health"
```

produces:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Allow: GET
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1047
Date: Wed, 19 Aug 2015 14:41:12 GMT
```

But I don't understand why. Both methods are using an HTTP GET. What needs to be enabled to support  headers-only response?
Not specifically looking for instructions on what needs to change in tomcat, so much as  (1) what is the difference here and (2) what is the English for what needs to happen, so I know what I'm looking for in Google.

Comment: Actually, `curl -I` is not `GET`.  That sends an HTTP `HEAD` request.

Comment: Ah, I read that response wrong.. Thou shalt always run verbose to debug. Thank you.